# move element up down jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an html span element with a background-image added. Using jquery, I am trying to make it move up and down Without stopping. But, unfortunately, I am not that familiar with jquery. Here is what I have:

```
    $(".cloud").animate( {"top": "+=20px"}, 3000, "linear", function() {
        $(".cloud").animate( {"top": "-=20px"}, 3000, "linear", function() {
            $this.moveCloud();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
move_bottom();
function move_bottom() {
    $(".cloud").animate({
        "margin-top": "20px"
    }, 3000, "linear", function () {
        move_top();//call function to move top
    });
}
function move_top() {
    $(".cloud").animate({
        "margin-top": "0px"
    }, 3000, "linear", function () {
        move_bottom();////call function to move bottom
    });
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2sVr9/)

You can also do it with css.

```
.cloud{animation:myfirst 5s infinite;-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s infinite;}
@keyframes myfirst{
    0%{margin-top:20px;}
    50%{margin-top:0px;}
    100%{margin-top:20px;}
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2sVr9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is all you need:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OWATONA/6/edit)**

```
var $cloud = $('.cloud');
(function loop(){
   $cloud.animate({top: (this.offsetTop>0?'-=':'+=')+20 }, 3000, "linear", loop);
})();
```